# Batch File SQL scripts in one single file

Tags: batch-file, sqlplus

I'm using a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) to run [sqlplus](/questions/tagged/sqlplus) with an `.sql` script:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /p usr=username: 
SET /p pwd=password: 
SET /p dbname=dbname: 
set /p tablename=tablename:

sqlplus %usr%/%pwd%@%dbname%.sql

select * from table where (something);
select (something) from table where (something);
exit;
```

The `.bat` file and `.sql` script needs to be in a single file, so I can't call an `.sql` file.
Any ideas? *(I'm using Windows 7 if that helps)*.

Comment: What about a self-extracting archive?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, but why not create the sql file from your bat file, write the sql commands to it, then execute it. When it's finished you can then delete the sql file.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /p usr=username: 
SET /p pwd=password: 
SET /p dbname=dbname: 
set /p tablename=tablename:

SET "sql1=select * from table where ^(something^)^;"
SET "sql2=select ^(something^) from table where ^(something^)^;"
SET "sql3=^(SELECT 1 + LEVEL-1 idx FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL ^<^= 10^)^;"

@echo %sql1% > temp.sql
@echo %sql2% >> temp.sql
@echo %sql3% >> temp.sql

sqlplus %usr%/%pwd% @temp.sql
```

code updated to allow for special characters which need to be escaped, use ^ to escape special characters.

You might also want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16412040/sqlplus-command-line-with-windows-batch-file)

Hope all goes well.

Comment: Yea but If I do something like this
echo (SELECT 1 + LEVEL-1 idx
  FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10) > temp.sql

It will say file not specified.

Comment: Hi Mark, I've updated my answer to allow for special characters.