# How to run a SQL query by connecting to SQL Plus through Batch file

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I need to run a SQL query by connecting to SQL Plus through Batch File.

Hence, I have created a batch file 'test.bat' in notepad and wrote the below contents :-

```
@echo off
set /p uname=Enter SQLPlus username:
set /p pwd=Enter SQLPlus password with instance:

sqlplus %uname%/%pwd%
select table_name from all tables 
order by table_name;
pause
```

When I run the batch file I am able to login to the SQLplus, but in cmd it prints SQL>

And I need to enter the select command manually.

How can I get the select statement run automatically?

Comment: Check [this](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/1075727/how-to-execute-sql-statement-under-bat-file), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16412040/sqlplus-command-line-with-windows-batch-file) and [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/87035/run-oracle-sql-script-and-exit-from-sqlplus-exe-via-command-prompt)

Comment: Tried the commands stated there, but still not working

Answer (score 0):

You can put your SELECT statement in another file which SQL*Plus will call with the `@` symbol:

```
c:\> type test.sql
select sysdate from dual;
exit

c:\> type test.bat
@echo off
set /p uname=Enter SQLPlus username:
set /p pwd=Enter SQLPlus password with instance:
sqlplus -s %uname%/%pwd% @test.sql

C:\> test.bat
Enter SQLPlus username: MYUSER
Enter SQLPlus password with instance: MYPWD

SYSDATE
-------------------
2020-10-28 19:59:46
```

If creating a separate .SQL file isn't possible you can try something like:

```
echo select sysdate from dual; | sqlplus -s %uname%/%pwd%
```

Comment: Thanks, @Marco however due to some restrictions I can't use separate SQL file

Comment: @AmarKumar I have expanded my answer

Comment: It is still prompting me the SQL> 

And still, the SQL commands aren't running

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do that by

- enclosing your code into brackets
- `echo`-ing every line within brackets
- and - if necessary (like in my example) - escaping `<` with 3 `^` signs.
- finally, *pipe* it to SQL*Plus

Looks kind of *stupid*, but it works. Here's how.

The `p1.bat` script:

```
@echo off
set /p uname=Enter SQLPlus username:
set /p pwd=Enter SQLPlus password with instance:

(
echo select table_name 
echo from user_tables 
echo where rownum ^^^<= 5 
echo order by table_name;
) | sqlplus %uname%/%pwd%
```

Testing:

```
c:\Temp>p1
Enter SQLPlus username:scott
Enter SQLPlus password with instance:tiger

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Sri Lis 28 21:45:34 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL>   2    3    4
TABLE_NAME
------------------------------
BONUS
DEPT
EMP
LINKS
SALGRADE

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

c:\Temp>
```

---

In my opinion, a separate `.SQL` file is simpler. See if you can avoid that "restriction" you mentioned.

Comment: Hi, @Littlefoot Actually I can't use separate .SQL files as there are multiple SQL queries to run in different parts of the batch file and I have some restrictions on creating new folders & any avoidable files as well.

Comment: OK, then use what I suggested.